# How do I sort string vectors based on 2nd column/3rd column etc?

Tags: c++

I have a

```
vector<string>data
```

organized as such

```
//NAME ID AGE
//NAME ID AGE
//NAME ID AGE
//NAME ID AGE
```

I can sort it by name alphabetically, how can I sort it in ascending order based on the 2nd column/3rd column instead? Thank you for any assistance and advice.

Comment: For most application, you should really replace `vector<string>` by something like `vector<Person>` where `Person` would have name, id and age field which would be properly initialized (with a `CreatePersonFromStringData` function. Then you could write a function object to sort data using the ID.

Comment: The fundamental flaw in the way you're going about this is that you read an entire line as a string, and just stored the string, and now fighting with this string that has everything in it.  Very few, if any, C++ programs naively read in the entire line as a string and store it somewhere, and then contort themselves into trying to work with the string.  What is done is to break up the string into logical components, so that the program can easily manipulate the data.  As others mentioned, you should be breaking up that data into logical components (a `class` or `struct` would be an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::sort`'s third overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) has a third parameter allows you to provide a function to do the ordering logic.

```
// get nth token from a string
std::string getnTh(const std::string & str, int n)
{
    std::istringstream strm(str);
    std::string result;
    for (int count = 0; count < n; count++)
    {
        if (!(strm >> result))
        {
            throw std::out_of_range("ran out of tokens before n");
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// get ID, second token, from string
std::string get_ID(const std::string str)
{
    return getnTh(str, 2);
}

// compare the ID field, second token,  in two strings
bool cmp_ID(const std::string &a, const std::string &b)
{
    std::string tokena = get_ID(a);
    std::string tokenb = get_ID(b);
    return tokena < tokenb;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> data {"c c c ", "b b b " , "a a a"};
    std::sort (data.begin(), data.end(), cmp_ID);
}
```

Note: This code could be crunched down a bit. I've broken it down step by step for easy reading.

Note: This is BRUTAL! It is constantly parsing the same `string`s over and over, a disgusting waste of effort.

Instead you should make a structure to store the already parsed string and store that structure in the `std::vector`.

```
// stores a person
struct person
{
    std::string name;
    std::string ID;
    std::string age;

    // constructor to parse an input string into a new person
    person(const std::string & in)
    {
        std::istringstream strm(in);
        if (!(strm >> name >> ID >> age))
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid person input");
        }
    }
};

// much simpler and faster compare function. All of the parsing is done once ahead of time.
bool cmp_ID(const person &a, const person &b)
{
    return a.ID < b.ID;
}

int main()
{
    // replaces vector<string> data
    std::vector<person> data {{"c c c"}, {"b b b"} , {"a a a"}};
    std::sort (data.begin(), data.end(), cmp_ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read those Strings by each character until you hit the first/second space.
Then you should be able to "filter" out the first/second attribute.

Comment: I've been searching for a method to 'filter' the first/second attribute but I can't find one that works with vector. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jolistic why can't you use Phil1970s suggestion above? (And detailed in the other answers)